# How powerful was Fugaku's Mangekyō Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, it's shown that Fugaku has his own Mangekyō Sharingan.

[image]

Is there any further information about Fugaku's Mangekyō Sharingan? How powerful are these eyes?

Comment: Not an answer, but I believe Fugakus Sharingan is only shown in filler. I’m certain there is little to no canonical information.

Comment: We know literally nothing about it except the he has it, what it looks like and the assumption it could manipulate a bijuu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know everything about it, though it's said to have the ability to control the Nine-Tails. It's the same way as how we don't know the abilities of Izuna's Mangekyo Sharingan.